# How do I go about solving an equation of the form $\tan (\frac{\pi}{x}) = \frac{c}{x}$ where c is a known constant?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I want to have an analytical way to solve for the number of sides a regular polygon has when given the area and apothem. A regular polygon with n-sides, an area of A, and an apothem of a, has these characteristics related by the formula $na^2\tan (\frac{\pi}{n}) = A$. With some rearranging, you get the equation $\tan (\frac{\pi}{x}) = \frac{c}{x}$ where c is $\frac{A}{a^2}$ I have found that c ranges from $\pi$ to $3\sqrt{3}$. $3\sqrt{3}$ corresponds to a triangle(the smallest number of sides possible in a polygon) and $\pi$ corresponds to a circle(infinite sides from a point of view). So the question now is, of course, what is the method of solving an equation of the form $\tan (\frac{\pi}{x}) = \frac{c}{x}$ where c is a known constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$f_n = n \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right), \quad 3 \le n \in \mathbb{N}$$
then $\pi \lt f_n \le 3\sqrt{3}$, and $f_n$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence.

The power series for $f_n$ is
$$f_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle \frac{U_{2 k + 1} \pi^{2 k + 1}}{n^{2 k} (2 k + 1)!}$$
where $U_i$ is Euler number or up/down number $i$, forming the OEIS sequence [A000111](https://oeis.org/A000111) (of positive monotonically increasing integers).

I do not believe there is an exact algebraic solution to solving
$$f_n = c \quad \iff \quad c = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle \frac{U_{2 k + 1} \pi^{2 k + 1}}{n^{2 k} (2 k + 1)!}$$
for $n$.

If we examine inverse of the relative difference to $\pi$,
$$r_n = \frac{\pi}{f_n - \pi} \approx 0.303935 n^2 + 0.000895 n - 1.20688$$
we can use the approximation to solve for $n$ when $c = f_n$ is known,
$$n = \left\lceil \sqrt{3.28986823 \frac{\pi}{c - \pi} + 4} \right\rfloor$$
which yields the correct result for $3 \le n \le 257942$.

Perhaps there exists a better invertible approximation $r_n$ that works for all $n$ you are interested in?

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty useful! Can you please tell me what area of math this is for the sums and approximations. It seems interesting.

Comment: @JohnPeter: The power series exist for all [trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions); I grabbed the one for tangent, and examined case $x = \pi/n$.  When you have a monotonic series $f_n$, the invertible approximation $r(n)$ only needs to be good enough so that $$\left\lvert \frac{r(n) - f_n}{f_n} \right\rvert \lt \frac{1}{2}$$ for $r(n)$ to yield the correct result when inverted, since $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  I don't know which field of maths this is, but I think it falls into numerical methods – even though it works fine for algebraic solutions too.

Comment: @JohnPeter: As to how I found $r_n$, I plotted $f_n$, and noticed the $\pi$ limit, then examined the difference to $\pi$, and then the inverted difference, $\pi/(f_n - \pi)$, and noticed that this last one is very, very close to a quadratic function.  I suspect a mathematician would say this is the guessing method, but I think of it as systematic exploration of the function, until you find something you can use.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and solution.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340734/could-these-polynomials-be-identified

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you could rewrite this into the form of

$tan(y) = k * y$ for $y=\frac{\pi}{x}$, $k = \frac{c}{\pi}$.

There is no analytical solution to this equation for $k=1$ from what I have found. Therefore, there is no generic way to do this for every $c$. Numerical approximations would be needed.

Here is a post about approximating the value for $k=1$: [Solution of tanx = x?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/solution-of-tanx-x)

Modify their update function to use $k*y$ instead of just $y$, and once you converge on a value of $y$, solve for $x$.

Comment: what post are you referring to ?

Comment: Oops didn't paste properly. Edited above